# Определить два вектора как функцию

Tags: функции, matlab

Ребята, всем привет!
Нужна помощь очень-очень. Matlab
Есть два вектора, нужно задать один как функцию другого. Через @, как function без разницы. Чтобы второй вектор стал функцией первого.
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, что Вы имеете в виду. Непонятно, что значит "чтобы вектор стал функцией". Вот есть два вектора, скажем, [1 2 3] и [4 5 6]. Какой результат ожидается?

Comment: Благодарю за попытку помочь, уже не актуально.